# Translation Matrix and Why non linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

When we translate a point $p_3 = (x,y,z)$ to coordinates $p_4 =(x + t_x , y + t_y ,z + t_z,1)$ we use $4 \times 4$ Translation matrix using homogenous coordinates, hence we add a $1$ to fourth coordinate of $p_4$.

But I could not find a matrix $M : R^3 \rightarrow R^4$ for which $M p_3 = p_4$. Note that I am talking about a $1$ on the fourt coordinate what ever vector  $p_3$ be.

Why can not we find such a generic translation matrix. Omit the case of matrix addition i.e.  $M$ may only be multiplication of other matrices.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot represent a translation in $3$-dimensional space with a matrix smaller than $4\times 4$. All $3\times 3$ matrices represent transformations which leave the origin fixed, because multiplying a matrix by the zero vector always yields the zero vector. Homogeneous coordinates might be used as a trick to solve this, but you need to add a vector entry and so switch to a $4\times 4$ matrix.

**ADDED LATER** (taken from comments)

In comments, the OP asked for a coordinate-free explanation. This is done by distinguishing "linear" vs "affine" or, more generally, "projective" transformations. Given a vector space $V$, one can build its [projective completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectivization) $\mathbb P(V\oplus \mathbb K)=\left[V\oplus \mathbb K \setminus\{(0,0)\}\right]/ \sim$, where $(v, \lambda)\sim(w, \mu)$ if and only if $ A(v, \lambda)=B(w, \mu)$ for scalars $A, B\in\mathbb K$. The space $V$ naturally embeds into its projective completion via the map $v\mapsto (v, 1)$. (This is the coordinate-free realization of the introduction of homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb K^n$).

This completion allows one to algebraically represent more transformations of $V$ than just the linear ones. The keyword here is [projective transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography). Translations are realized as projective transformation via the following trick:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccc}
T_h(v)=v+h & \leftrightarrow&\begin{bmatrix} I_V & h \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} v+h \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
The relevance of this to the question is that the translation is realized as a transformation of the projective completion of $V$. This needs one more coordinate to be described as a matrix, hence (if $\dim V=3$) a $4\times 4$ matrix necessarily.

Comment: THanks but the explanation I am looking for is about using vector spaces and other abstract math.

Comment: I know what you said but what I look for is somewhat a proof related to pure linear algebra

Comment: @camoka: In "pure linear algebra" terms, the issue is to be explained in terms of "linear" vs "projective" transformations. A translation is not a linear transformation, because it does not fix the origin. But it is a projective transformation (indeed, it is an *affine* one). So, if you call $V$ your vector space, you can represent your translation $T$ by imbedding $V$ into a projective space $P(V)$ (which, in coordinates, amounts to introducing homogeneous coordinates) and then using the machinery of representation of projective transformations.

Comment: More precisely, to represent 

$$T\colon V \to V$$

as a projective transformation, you need to regard it as a mapping

$$T\colon P(V) \to P(V).$$

Both $T\colon V\to P(V)$ and $T\colon P(V)\to V$ won't work.

Comment: This is why you will need to add a "row" dimension and a "column" dimension, and so use a $4\times 4$ matrix. Neither a $4\times 3$ nor a $3\times 4$ matrix will work.